# Linux - Child process to survive parent process tree kill

Tags: bash, unix

**Motivation:**

In a Java program, I'm setting a bash script to be executed on `-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError`. This script is responsible for uploading the heap-dump to HDFS. However, quite often only a part of the file gets uploaded.

I'm suspecting the JVM gets killed by cluster manager before the upload script completes. My guess is the JVM receives a process group kill signal and takes the bash script, i.e. its child process, down too.

**The Question:**

Is there a way in unix to run a sub-process in such a way that it does not die when it's parent receives a group kill signal?

Comment: You could trap the signals, have a look at this: [http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_12_02.html](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_12_02.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `disown`. Start the process in the background and then disown it, and any kill signals to the process parent will no longer be propagated to the child.

Script would look something like:

```
./handler_script &
disown
```